# Atom to adjust size of the Julia plot in the Plot Pane

Tags: plot, julia, atom-editor

I use Atom as the editor for writing my Julia code, and I was wondering if there is anyway that Julia plots are adjusted in terms of their size according to the size of the plots pane. That would be a very useful feature if you have a lot of tabs open. When I resize the pane, the image size stays the same, unlike in RStudio where you have a bit of more control over the size.

Comment: If you regenerate the plot, it should change size to match the pane.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. I changed the size of the pane first and then regenerated the plot and it was fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you regenerate the plot, it should change size to match the pane.